# the initializatio of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

A part of a code I'm practising is as follows:

```
void outputBarChart()
{
    cout<<"\nOverall grade distribution: "<<endl;
    const int frequencySize = 11;
    int frequency[frequencySize] = {};

    for(int student = 0; student < student; ++student)
        for(int test = 0; test < tests; ++test)
            ++frequency[ (grades[student][test])/10 ];

    for(int counter = 0; counter < frequencySize; ++counter)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
            cout<<" 0-9: "<<endl;
        else if (counter == 10)
            cout<<" 100: "<<endl;
        else
        {
            cout<<counter * 10<<"-"<<(counter*10)+9<<": ";
            for (int stars = 0; stars < frequency[counter]; ++stars)
                cout<<"*";
            cout<<endl;
        }

        //cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

The array ***frequency*** is supposed to be initialized in the following line:

```
++frequency[ (grades[student][test])/10 ];
```

but it seems that it is not working that way because the following line does not run:

```
for (int stars = 0; stars < frequency[counter]; ++stars)
cout<<"*";
```

how to initialize ***frequency*** correctly?

Comment: What is the valid range for the elements of `grades[student][test]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your for loop is broken:

```
for (int student = 0; student < student; ++student)
```

I imagine it should be:

```
for (int student = 0; student < students; ++student)
                                       ^
```

Comment: @leemes: Or just use clang: `foo.cc:12:34: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]`

Comment: @BillLynch Yep, but there are other bugs which static analysis won't find. I found that training your eye to see such "silly" bugs (like off-by-1, or wrong variable name) is always well-spent time. And codefights is the gamification of this ;)

Answer (score -2):

The `++operator` is an incrementer. Whatever was in the memory before it was allocated to the array may (unreliably) still be there. Try initializing it to a set value with something like:

```
for(int i=0; i< frequencySize;i++) frequency[i]=0;
```

Comment: The array is already initialized to zero as part of this line: `int frequency[frequencySize] = {};`